# Different struct attributes "published" for JSON Encoder/Decoder

Tags: json, encoding, go, decoding

I need to export some large structs via JSON, and take back JSON strings for updating **only some** of it's attributes.

Let's have following struct:

```
type House struct {
    Name   string  `json:"name"`
    Rooms  int     `json:"rooms_count"`
    Owner  *Owner  `json:"-"`
}
```

Encoding that with `encoding/json` will result in a JSON string like

```
{"name":"some name", "rooms_count":5}
```

I now get this JSON string:

```
{"name":"some other name", "rooms_count":7, Owner:{something...}}
```

The user wants to change every attribute. `Owner` is not allowed, because it's not exported. But I only want to only permit changes of `rooms_count`. Is there any way of saying that some attributes should be exported with the `Encoder`, but not be used by the `Decoder`? Having to write all these checks manualy would be very unpleasant.

Comment: Your explanation is difficult to follow I'm afraid. Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/golang-json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields It allows a private struct with exported fields, so you can defined what you want to be accessed with getters/setters but export the whole struct.

Comment: @minikomi: No, I want to export different fields for the Encoder than for the Decoder. Because the user should be able to see more fields than he is allowed to change. A very common task if you program an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a patch for the encoding/json package and opened a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4747).

It just adds 2 tag options for structs for ignoring struct fields in the `Encoder` and `Decoder` separately. Example where all two fields are encoded/exported, but only `Name` is getting decoded/updated:

```
type House struct {
    Name    string    `json:"house_name"`
    PubDate time.Time `json:"pub_date,nodecode"`
}
```

Comment: Go Issue 4747 Status: WorkingAsIntended.

Comment: Nonetheless the best solution I could find. I'm using a custom json encoder package now whch saves me hundreds of lines of code and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In your exact case, simply unmarshalling to a new struct and doing a `currentStruct.Rooms = newStruct.Rooms` is exactly what you want.

For that type of custom marshalling, there's not a totally straightforward way to do it.  The best you could get is two identical structs with different tags for different occasions and a bit of reflection to perform the conversion between them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, so there seems to be no other way. Unfortunately thats exactly what I absolutely do not want. I'm trying to modify the json package and add a "notencoding"/"notdecoding" tag now.