# How to flatten JSON for a generic type in Go

Tags: json, go, generics, marshalling

I'm trying to implement HAL in Go, just to see if I can. This means that I've got a `HAL` type that is generic over the payload, and also contains the `_links`:

```
type HAL[T any] struct {
    Payload T
    Links   Linkset `json:"_links,omitempty"`
}
```

In the HAL spec, the payload is actually at the top level and not nested inside it - like, e.g. Siren would be. So that means given the following:

```
type TestPayload struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Answer int    `json:"answer"`
}

    hal := HAL[TestPayload]{
        Payload: TestPayload{
            Name:   "Graham",
            Answer: 42,
        },
        Links: Linkset{
            "self": {
                {Href: "/"},
            },
        },
    }
```

The resulting JSON should be:

```
{
    "name": "Graham",
    "answer": 42,
    "_links": {
      "self": {"href": "/"}
    }
}
```

But I can't work out a good way to get this JSON marshalling to work.

I've seen suggestions of embedding the payload as an anonymous member, which works great *if it's not generic*. Unfortunately, you can't embed generic types in that way so that's a non-starter.

I probably could write a `MarshalJSON` method that will do the job, but I'm wondering if there's any standard way to achieve this instead?

I've got a Playground link with this working code to see if it helps: https://go.dev/play/p/lorK5Wv-Tri

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately you can't embed the type parameter `T`. I'll also argue that in the general case you shouldn't attempt to flatten the output JSON. By constraining `T` with `any`, you are admitting literally any type, however not all types have fields to promote into your `HAL` struct.

This is semantically inconsistent.

If you attempt to embed a type with no fields, the output JSON will be different. Using the solution with `reflect.StructOf` as an example, nothing stops me from instantiating `HAL[[]int]{ Payload: []int{1,2,3}, Links: ... }`, in which case the output would be:

```
{"X":[1,2,3],"Links":{"self":{"href":"/"}}}
```

This makes your JSON serialization change with the types used to instantiate `T`, which is not easy to spot for someone who reads your code. The code is less predictable, and you are effectively working against the generalization that type parameters provide.

Using the named field `Payload T` is just better, as:

- the output JSON is always (for most intents and purposes) consistent with the actual struct
- unmarshalling also keeps a predictable behavior
- scalability of the code is not an issue, as you don't have to repeat all of the fields of `HAL` to build an anonymous struct

OTOH, if your requirements are *precisely* to marshal structs as flattened and everything else with a key (as it might be the case with HAL types), at the very least make it obvious by checking `reflect.ValueOf(hal.Payload).Kind() == reflect.Struct` in the `MarshalJSON` implementation, and provide a default case for whatever else `T` could be. Will have to be repeated in `JSONUnmarshal`.

Here is a solution with reflection that works when `T` is not a struct and scales when you add more fields to the main struct:

```
// necessary to marshal HAL without causing infinite loop
// can't declare inside the method due to a current limitation with Go generics
type tmp[T any] HAL[T]

func (h HAL[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // examine Payload, if it isn't a struct, i.e. no embeddable fields, marshal normally
    v := reflect.ValueOf(h.Payload)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Pointer || v.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return json.Marshal(tmp[T](h))
    }

    // flatten all fields into a map
    m := make(map[string]any)
    // flatten Payload first
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        key := jsonkey(v.Type().Field(i))
        m[key] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }
    // flatten the other fields
    w := reflect.ValueOf(h)
    // start at 1 to skip the Payload field
    for i := 1; i < w.NumField(); i++ {
        key := jsonkey(w.Type().Field(i))
        m[key] = w.Field(i).Interface()
    }
    return json.Marshal(m)
}

func jsonkey(field reflect.StructField) string {
    // trickery to get the json tag without omitempty and whatnot
    tag := field.Tag.Get("json")
    tag, _, _ = strings.Cut(tag, ",")
    if tag == "" {
        tag = field.Name
    }
    return tag
}
```

With `HAL[TestPayload]` or `HAL[*TestPayload]` it outputs:

```
{"answer":42,"name":"Graham","_links":{"self":{"href":"/"}}}
```

With `HAL[[]int]` it outputs:

```
{"Payload":[1,2,3],"_links":{"self":{"href":"/"}}}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/bWGXWj_rC5F

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a custom JSON codec that inserts `_links` field at the end of the JSON jenerated for the payload.

Marshaller.

```
type Link struct {
    Href string `json:"href"`
}

type Linkset map[string]Link

type HAL[T any] struct {
    Payload T
    Links   Linkset `json:"_links,omitempty"`
}

func (h HAL[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    payloadJson, err := json.Marshal(h.Payload)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(payloadJson) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Empty payload")
    }
    if h.Links != nil {
        return appendField(payloadJson, "_links", h.Links)
    }
    return payloadJson, nil
}

func appendField[T any](raw []byte, fieldName string, v T) ([]byte, error) {
    // The JSON data must be braced in {}
    if raw[0] != '{' || raw[len(raw)-1] != '}' {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Not an object: %s", string(raw))
    }
    valJson, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Add the field at the end of the json text
    result := bytes.NewBuffer(raw[:len(raw)-1])
    // Append `"<fieldName>":value`
    // Insert comma if the `raw` object is not empty
    if len(raw) > 2 {
        result.WriteByte(',')
    }
    // tag
    result.WriteByte('"')
    result.WriteString(fieldName)
    result.WriteByte('"')
    // colon
    result.WriteByte(':')
    // value
    result.Write(valJson)
    // closing brace
    result.WriteByte('}')
    return result.Bytes(), nil
}
```

The marshaller returns an error if `Payload` serializes to something other than JSON object. The reason is that the codec can add `_links` field to objects only.

Unmarshaller:

```
func (h *HAL[T]) UnmarshalJSON(raw []byte) error {
    // Unmarshal fields of the payload first.
    // Unmarshal the whole JSON into the payload, it is safe:
    // decorer ignores unknow fields and skips "_links".
    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &h.Payload); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Get "_links": scan trough JSON until "_links" field
    links := make(Linkset)
    exists, err := extractField(raw, "_links", &links)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if exists {
        h.Links = links
    }
    return nil
}

func extractField[T any](raw []byte, fieldName string, v *T) (bool, error) {
    // Scan through JSON until field is found
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(raw))
    t := must(decoder.Token())
    // should be `{`
    if t != json.Delim('{') {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("Not an object: %s", string(raw))
    }
    t = must(decoder.Token())
    if t == json.Delim('}') {
        // Empty object
        return false, nil
    }
    for decoder.More() {
        name, ok := t.(string)
        if !ok {
            return false, fmt.Errorf("must never happen: expected string, got `%v`", t)
        }
        if name != fieldName {
            skipValue(decoder)
        } else {
            if err := decoder.Decode(v); err != nil {
                return false, err
            }
            return true, nil
        }
        if decoder.More() {
            t = must(decoder.Token())
        }
    }
    return false, nil
}

func skipValue(d *json.Decoder) {
    braceCnt := 0
    for d.More() {
        t := must(d.Token())
        if t == json.Delim('{') || t == json.Delim('[') {
            braceCnt++
        }
        if t == json.Delim('}') || t == json.Delim(']') {
            braceCnt--
        }
        if braceCnt == 0 {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The unmarshaller fails on non-object as well. It is required to read `_links` field. For that the input must be an object.

The full example: https://go.dev/play/p/E3NN2T7Fbnm

```
func main() {
    hal := HAL[TestPayload]{
        Payload: TestPayload{
            Name:   "Graham",
            Answer: 42,
        },
        Links: Linkset{
            "self": Link{Href: "/"},
        },
    }
    bz := must(json.Marshal(hal))
    println(string(bz))

    var halOut HAL[TestPayload]
    err := json.Unmarshal(bz, &halOut)
    if err != nil {
        println("Decode failed: ", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", halOut)
}
```

Output:

```
{"name":"Graham","answer":42,"_links":{"self":{"href":"/"}}}
main.HAL[main.TestPayload]{Payload:main.TestPayload{Name:"Graham", Answer:42}, Links:main.Linkset{"self":main.Link{Href:"/"}}}
```

Comment: this is an acceptable solution in theory, if the complexity of the marshal/unmarshal is warranted for the use, however it's hard to get right. In fact your code panics if `HAL` is instantiated with something other than a struct

Comment: @blackgreen sure thing it fails. There is no way to add `_links` field to anything other than an object. And there is no way to extract `_links` from non-objects.  What do you mean by *complexity*? This codec is much simpler compared to the `json.Decoder`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, embedding is the easiest way, and as you wrote, you can't currently embed a type parameter.

You may however construct a type that embeds the type param using reflection. We may instantiate this type and marshal it instead.

For example:

```
func (hal HAL[T]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
        {
            Name:      "X",
            Anonymous: true,
            Type:      reflect.TypeOf(hal.Payload),
        },
        {
            Name: "Links",
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(hal.Links),
        },
    })

    v := reflect.New(t).Elem()
    v.Field(0).Set(reflect.ValueOf(hal.Payload))
    v.Field(1).Set(reflect.ValueOf(hal.Links))

    return json.Marshal(v.Interface())
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/t5wpzZx1cm3)):

```
{"name":"Graham","answer":42,"Links":{"self":{"href":"/"}}}
```

See related: [Adding Arbitrary fields to json output of an unknown struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709680/adding-arbitrary-fields-to-json-output-of-an-unknown-struct/42715610#42715610)

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple.

Yes it would be nice to embed the type - but since it's not currently possible (as of `go1.19`) to embed a generic type - just write it out inline:

```
body, _ = json.Marshal(
    struct {
        TestPayload
        Links       Linkset `json:"_links,omitempty"`
    }{
        TestPayload: hal.Payload,
        Links:       hal.Links,
    },
)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/8yrB-MzUVK-

```
{
    "name": "Graham",
    "answer": 42,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, the constraint type needs to be referenced twice - but all the customization is code-localized, so no need for a custom marshaler.

Comment: The `,inline` option is unknown to the `encoding/json` library. What makes this work is purely the fact of embedding.

Comment: Ah! Needed in `yaml` - good to know.

Comment: by embedding `TestPayload` explicitly, the marshalling is not generic anymore, while `HAL[T]` in the OP is generic

Comment: To use generic types one must instantiate the type i.e `HAL[TestPayload]`. The above is more wordy, yes - repeating the type definition - but essentially the same: providing a concrete type at compilation-time.  Given the current embedding constraints, it's the closest the OP can get.