# How to marshal struct when some members are protected/inner/hidden

Tags: go, marshalling

How do ensure the fields in this `LookupCode` struct are included when marshalling?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type LookupCode struct {
    code string `json:"code"`
    name string `json:"name"`
}

func (l *LookupCode) GetCode() string {
    return l.code
}

func main() {
    c := &LookupCode{
        code: "A",
        name: "Apple",
    }

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(c, "", "\t")

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/my52DAn0-Z

Comment: possible duplicate of [golang json and dealing with unexported fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/golang-json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can by implementing the json.Marshaller interface:

Full Example: http://play.golang.org/p/8mIcPwX92P

```
// Implement json.Unmarshaller
func (l *LookupCode) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var tmp struct {
        Code string `json:"code"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    l.code = tmp.Code
    l.name = tmp.Name
    return nil 
}

func (l *LookupCode) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        Code string `json:"code"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }{
        Code: l.code,
        Name: l.name,
    })
}
```

Comment: Minor point,  but since the fields of `LookupCode` are unexported and thus not used by the json package, the struct tags aren't actually used for anything, and they can (and should) be removed.

Answer (score 5):

`encode/json` cannot marshal unexported fields. Change your code to:

```
type LookupCode struct {
    Code string `json:"code"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

and do the same wherever you use `code` or `name`.

**Playground**: http://play.golang.org/p/rak0nVCNGI

**Edit**

The limitation is due to the reflection used when marshalling the struct. If you need to keep your values unexported, you must implement the [`json.Marshaller` interface](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and do the encoding manually.

Answer (score 0):

if the struct has **only** string-type fields,you can try this **hack** way.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/bitly/go-simplejson"
)

type A struct {
    name string `json:"name"`
    code string `json:"code"`
}

func marshal(a A) ([]byte, error) {
    j := simplejson.New()
    va := reflect.ValueOf(&a)
    vt := va.Elem()
    types := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    for i := 0; i < vt.NumField(); i++ {
        j.Set(types.Field(i).Tag.Get("json"), fmt.Sprintf("%v", reflect.Indirect(va).Field(i)))
    }
    return j.MarshalJSON()
}

func main() {
    a := A{name: "jessonchan", code: "abc"}
    b, _ := marshal(a)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```