# GOLANG unmarshal dynamic JSON

Tags: json, go

I am very new to GOLANG.

I have been trying for quite some time now to unmarshal an ethereum RPC JSON which has a dynamic structure. No GOLANG struct and map setup I did worked and I am able to get the stateDiff entries (3) but all lower structs seem not to be filled ith any data. So I am able to loop through all the 3 entries but then don't know how to access the values below and when dumping the unmarshal result, I see that GOLANG is not delivering the data anyway into StateDiff

JSON FILE:

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":1,
   "result":{
      "output":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
      "stateDiff":{
         "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000":{
            "balance":{
               "*":{
                  "from":"0x45acecdfadb71366cf",
                  "to":"0x45aced3909536ccacf"
               }
            },
            "code":"=",
            "nonce":"=",
            "storage":{
               
            }
         },
         "0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f":{
            "balance":"=",
            "code":"=",
            "nonce":"=",
            "storage":{
               "0x86a60af761556602732bbdeaef13ba6e2481f83362d3489389f51353d86a6ac3":{
                  "*":{
                     "from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                     "to":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710"
                  }
               },
               "0xb0cf6f3c0836765b9dee3d1537458f10fe99447508adc172c1f633ac7352aaa8":{
                  "*":{
                     "from":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000092f379a04d2b0",
                     "to":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000092f379a04aba0"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "0x6dbe810e3314546009bd6e1b29f9031211cda5d2":{
            "balance":{
               "*":{
                  "from":"0x41c41fc2c0247860",
                  "to":"0x41c3c66723c4155c"
               }
            },
            "code":"=",
            "nonce":{
               "*":{
                  "from":"0x741",
                  "to":"0x742"
               }
            },
            "storage":{
               
            }
         }
      },
      "trace":[
         
      ],
      "vmTrace":null
   }
}
```

I have tried to unmarshal the JSON into the following structure (among many) and i can't get the values such as **result>stateDiff>0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000>balance>*>from**
Struct below is just one of many i tried. I can't get anything below the entry 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

```
type structChange struct {
    Changes map[string]string `json:"*"`
}

type structStateDiff struct {
    Balance *structChange            `json:"balance"`
    Code    string                    `json:"code"`
    Nonce   string                    `json:"nonce"`
    Storage map[string]*structChange `json:"storage"`
}

type res_trace_replayTransaction struct {
    Jsonrpc string `json:"jsonrpc"`
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
    Result  struct {
        Output    string                      `json:"output"`
        StateDiff map[string]*structStateDiff `json:"stateDiff"`
        Trace     []interface{}               `json:"trace"`
        VMTrace   interface{}                 `json:"vmTrace"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

EDIT:
Code for umarshal

```
retObj := rpcCall(jstring)

var callResponse res_trace_replayTransaction
err := json.Unmarshal(retObj, &callResponse)
```

Comment: Please work through Go tutorial : https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started and then read a Go Json tutorial such as  https://gobyexample.com/json
I strongly recommend against anonymous.  Instead define top level `type`s for each struct and then use the type name within structs that contain it.

Comment: Read it already and I am not able to resolve this.

Comment: Go read the json example again then, more closely.  One of the first 3 paragraphs tells you what you did wrong: "Only exported fields will be encoded/decoded in JSON. Fields must start with capital letters to be exported."

Comment: "No GOLANG struct and map setup I did worked"  I would use `struct`s for this - not anonymous, but named struct types - but you don't *need* to use `struct`s.  You can also do something like https://go.dev/play/p/P4ryK-9wuVl - the downside here is that you have to do all your own type checking, so that's why `struct`s are better

Comment: Also you didn't include your unmarshalling code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(un)marshalling json golang not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595096/unmarshalling-json-golang-not-working)

Comment: I have realized I copied a very first version up here of my structs. My bad. The capital letter issue I am aware of. I get the message panic: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field structStateDiff.result.stateDiff.balance of type main.
structChange


unmarshaling code added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by default the `encoding/json` package can unmarshal a JSON string into a Go `string`, and it can unmarshal a JSON object into a Go `map` or a Go `struct`. Additionally it can unmarshal any JSON value into an empty `interface{}`.

Also note that Go is a *statically* typed language, if you specify a value to be of type `T1` then, at runtime, you cannot change it's type to `T2`. There is just no way to do it, no way to change a value's type.

So if you define a field to be of some `struct` type, you cannot, by default, unmarshal a JSON string into it. And equally if you define a field to be of type `string`, you cannot, by default, unmarshal a JSON object into it.

But because JSON itself allows for a dynamic structure the `encoding/json` package provides two interfaces that give you the ability to customize how the JSON is [marshaled](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.5#Marshaler) and [unmarshaled](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.5#Unmarshaler).

So if you have a JSON property (e.g. `"balance"` or `"nonce"`) that can be either `"="` (a string), or `{ ... }` (an object), you will need to declare a custom type that implements the `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` interfaces that know how to properly marshal and unmarshal the JSON value.

For example:

```golang
type structChange struct {
    Changes map[string]string `json:"*"`
}

func (s structChange) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // if empty retrun `"="`
    if len(s.Changes) == 0 {
        return []byte(`"="`), nil
    }

    // otherwise marshal as is
    type T structChange
    return json.Marshal(T(s))
}

func (s *structChange) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // if `"="`, ignore
    if string(data) == `"="` {
        return nil
    }

    // otherwise assume it's a valid object
    type T structChange
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*T)(s))
}
```

<sub>NOTE: the temporary type `T` above is used to avoid a stack overflow caused by an infinite recursive call to the `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` methods.</sub>

https://go.dev/play/p/yfsTrMozZ2Z

Comment: So the issue is all about the "*" field in balance. I have now removed this and it works, unfortunately is this not the solution. How can you unmarshal a "*" key field?

Comment: @ThomasMiller I don't understand what you are saying. Please update your question with the new code and explain, in clear terms, the problem/error that you are now facing.

Comment: @ThomasMiller generally you need to do a nil-check, e.g. `if x != nil { ...`, for any `x` that you want to use but that *could* be `nil` in the context in which it is used. It's not possible to be more specific without seeing the actual code and the full stack trace of the panic. If you want more help you need to update the question with the new information. Or open a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually found this solution right now and saw your response. I was checking too high up in the structure for nil instead of the lowest field that actually mattered. Now, i catch the nil case and it won't throw error