# Unmarshaling top-level json object in golang

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to parse a node package.json file in golang and I've got the following struct:

```
type packageJson struct {
    scripts         map[string]interface{} `json:"scripts"`
    dependencies    map[string]interface{} `json:"dependencies"`
    devDependencies map[string]interface{} `json:"devDependencies"`
}

...

var content packageJson
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &content); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

When I parse the package file however the struct is not being populated (not getting an error though). I suspect it is because the content is an object itself (i.e.: `{ "scripts":"...", ... }`) and the Unmarshal method wants to convert it into a `map[string]interface{}`. Any suggestions how to get around this "issue"? I tried creating a wrapper struct and using `jpath` but to no avail. Thanks!

Note: I could do this

```
var content map[string]interface{}
...
if val, ok := content["scripts"]; !ok { ... }
```

but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make struct fields public.

Comment: I thought visibility doesn't matter, but I guess it's because Unmarshal takes a pointer and is outside the scope. It works now! Thanks.

Comment: It's because un-exported fields can't be accessed by any other packages, even with reflection.

Comment: Visibility matters because unmarshaller uses reflection and just will not be able to access private fields. There is some discussion on that subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/golang-json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields