# Unmarshal a YAML to a struct with unexpected fields in Go

Tags: go, struct, yaml, unmarshalling

I encountered an issue while trying to unmarshal a struct with an unexported field using `github.com/go-yaml/yaml`. The struct looks like:

```
type Example struct {
    ExportedField   string                     `yaml:"exported-field"`
    OneMoreExported string                     `yaml:"one-more-exported"`
    unexportedField map[string]*AnotherExample `yaml:"unexported-field"`
}

type AnotherExample struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}
```

And I'd like to unmarshal such YAML as

```
exported-field: lorem ipsum
one-more-exported: dolor set
unexported-field:
  something:
    name: anything
```

What I tried is a custom unmarshaler:

```
func (example *Example) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    type Alias Example
    tmp := struct {
        UnexportedField map[string]*AnotherExample `yaml:"unexported-field"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(example),
    }
    if err := unmarshal(&tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if tmp.UnexportedField != nil {
        example.unexportedField = tmp.UnexportedField
    }
    example.CopyJobNonNil(Example(*tmp.Alias)) // Copies all the non-nil fields from the passed Example instance

    return nil
}
```

`tmp` after calling `unmarshal()` doesn't contain any fields but unexportedField — other fields seems to be omitted.

The reproduced issue on Go Playground (although it isn't working due to the dependencies): https://play.golang.org/p/XZg7tEPGXna

Answer (score 2):

Because most Go unmarshalling packages (including the `encoding/*` packages) use the `reflect` package to get at struct fields, and `reflect` can't access unexported struct fields, the unmarshaler can't parse into unexported fields.

That said, there is still a way to do it. You can unmarshall the YAML into an an unexported type with public fields, which can then be embedded into an exported type. Getters and setters in the same package can just use the embedded struct.

For example:

```
// Define the types...

type innerData struct {
    ExportedField string
    unexportedField string
}

type Data struct {
    innerData
}


// and then...

d := Data{}
DoSomeUnmarshalling(yamlbytes, &d.innerData)


// and then you can use getters/setters/whatever on `Data`

func (d *Data) GetUnexported() string {
    return d.innerData.unexportedField;
}
```

(warning: completely untested)

See [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields) for reference.