# My struct is not encoding correctly and is missing a property

Tags: go, struct

```
type ApiResponse struct {
    Success bool     `json:"success"`
    Errors  []string `json:"errors"`
}

type NewSessionResponse struct {
    ApiResponse     `json:"apiResponse"`
    authToken   string `json:"authToken"`
}
```

In my handler I am doing this:

```
resp := NewSessionResponse{ApiResponse{true, []string{}}, "auth123"}

json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
```

The response I am seeing is this:

```
{
    apiResponse: {
        success: true,
        errors: [ ]
    }
}
```

Why isn't my authToken property in the JSON result?

Comment: @Anuruddha sorry that was a typo fixed.

Comment: Because it's not exported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authToken` filed is an unexported field. Json library does not have the power to view fields using reflect unless they are exported. A package can only view the unexported fields of types within its own package.

You can export the filed to get this working

```
type NewSessionResponse struct {
    ApiResponse     `json:"apiResponse"`
    AuthToken   string `json:"authToken"`
}
```

FYI: Exported identifiers https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers