# Unable to parse json value in golang program

Tags: json, go

The below is my sample code in Go. I want to parse the value of B and check value of key 'status'

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ValidateUser struct {
    UserName, status, sessionID, timestamp string
}

func main() {
    // This JSON contains an int array.
    B := "{\"UserName\": \"Moulali\",\"status\": \"valid_user\"}"

    fmt.Println("outside if")
    fmt.Println("ValueOfB = %v", B)

    bytes := []byte(B)

    var validateUser ValidateUser
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &validateUser)
    if validateUser.status == "valid_user" {
        fmt.Printf("Valid User")
    }
}
```

Comment: `status` should be exported. check this out: https://play.golang.org/p/NahMuLoWot0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`status` should be exported (`ValidateUser.Status`). Just one slight modification to your code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ValidateUser struct {
    UserName string
    // export Status, and map to json field `status`
    Status string `json: "status"`
    sessionID string
    timestamp string
}

func main() {
    // This JSON contains an int array.
    B := "{\"UserName\": \"Moulali\",\"status\": \"valid_user\"}"

    fmt.Println("outside if")
    fmt.Println("ValueOfB = %v", B)

    bytes := []byte(B)

    var validateUser ValidateUser
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &validateUser)

    // reference ValidateUser.Status (capital s)
    if validateUser.Status == "valid_user" {
        fmt.Printf("Valid User")
    }
}
```

Link to code: https://play.golang.org/p/WN4cOz_YBLF

Answer (score 0):

`json` package methods can only deal with public fields. Here, `status` is a private field and it is not accessible form `json.Marshal` or `json.Unmarshal`.

If you want to have the field name as `status`, you can specify that in `json tag`.

See the example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ValidateUser struct {
    UserName             string `json:"UserName"`
    Status               string `json:"Status"`
    sessionID, timestamp string
}

func main() {
    // This JSON contains an int array.
    B := "{\"UserName\": \"Moulali\",\"status\": \"valid_user\"}"

    fmt.Println("outside if")
    fmt.Println("ValueOfB = %v", B)

    bytes := []byte(B)

    var validateUser ValidateUser
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &validateUser)
    if validateUser.Status == "valid_user" {
        fmt.Printf("Valid User: %v \n", validateUser)

        jsonMarshalled, _ := json.Marshal(validateUser) //checking marshal
        fmt.Println(string(jsonMarshalled))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
outside if
ValueOfB = %v {"UserName": "Moulali","status": "valid_user"}
Valid User: {Moulali valid_user  } 
{"UserName":"Moulali","Status":"valid_user"}
```