# How to bind json stringify data in golang custom struct type?

Tags: json, go, bind, stringify

How to bind json stringify data in golang custom struct type?

js ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url : url
    , data : JSON.stringify('{"nowBlockPositionX":3,"nowBlockPositionY":0,"nowBlock":{"O":0}}')
})
```

go custom struct

```
type demo struct {
    nowBlockPositionX  int                `form:"nowBlockPositionX" json:"nowBlockPositionX"`
    NowBlockPositionY  int                `form:"nowBlockPositionY" json:"nowBlockPositionY"`
    NowBlock           map[string]int     `form:"nowBlock" json:"nowBlock" query:"nowBlock"`
}
```

don't binding this

```
demo := new(demo)
if err := c.Bind(demo); err != nil {
    c.Logger().Error(err)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. Export your fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Comment: It is totally in @Flimzy link

Comment: duplicate a similar question is asked here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919830/go-gin-get-request-body-json/70077055#70077055

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the `demo` struct. The field in the struct need to be exported. Just change the first character of each field to be in uppercase.

Then remove the `form:` and `query:` tags. You only need the `json:` tag.

```
type demo struct {
    NowBlockPositionX  int                `json:"NowBlockPositionX"`
    NowBlockPositionY  int                `json:"NowBlockPositionY"`
    NowBlock           map[string]int     `json:"NowBlock"`
}
```

---

There are also few problems appear on your javascript code, on the `$.ajax` statement.

Do this two things:

1. Set the content type header to `application/json`.
2. Remove the `JSON.stringify()` since your data already in string.

Working code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: '{"nowBlockPositionX":3,"nowBlockPositionY":0,"nowBlock":{"O":0}}'
 })
```

Comment: nit-pick: the json tags are there, and your tags are incorrect (start with capital `N`). In your example, the JSON tags are actually not needed, default behaviour is to map JSON onto field names directly anyway