# Go gin get request body json

Tags: go, http-post

Im using postman to post data and in the body Im putting some simple json

Request Body

```
{
    "order":"1",
    "Name":"ts1"
}
```

I need to transfer the data to json and I try like following,
and I wasnt able to get json, any idea what is missing

```
router.POST("/user", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var f interface{}
        //value, _ := c.Request.GetBody()
        //fmt.Print(value)

        err2 := c.ShouldBindJSON(&f)
        if err2 == nil {
            err = client.Set("id", f, 0).Err()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

        }
```

The f is not a json and Im getting an error, any idea how to make it work? 
The error is:

```
redis: can't marshal map[string]interface {} (implement encoding.BinaryMarshaler)
```

I use https://github.com/go-redis/redis#quickstart

If I remove the the body and use hard-coded code like this I was able to set the data, **it works**

```
json, err := json.Marshal(Orders{
    order:   "1",
    Name: "tst",
})

client.Set("id", json, 0).Err()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error? What does "f is not a json" mean?

Comment: @CeriseLimón - please see my update

Comment: @hmm - please see my update

Comment: It looks like your goal is to store the posted JSON document to Redis.  If so, slurp up the body into a []byte and store the []byte in Redis.  Do not decode the JSON to Go values.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - you mean something like this: `  buf := make([]byte, 1024)
  value, _ := c.Request.Body.Read(buf)` and use the value in redis?

Comment: @BenoOdr See hmm answer for how to do it.  The code in your comment is not guaranteed to read the entire request body including the case where the length of the body is < 1024.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - thanks ill try it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you only want to pass the request body JSON to Redis as a value, then you do not need to bind the JSON to a value. Read the raw JSON from the request body directly and just pass it through:

```
jsonData, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
err = client.Set("id", jsonData, 0).Err()
```

Comment: I was tried it, but nothing show. c.Request.Body is empty

Comment: I'm getting empty response too

Comment: Since Go 1.16 `io.ReadAll` should be used instead of `ioutil.ReadAll` <https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil>

Comment: This will not work if you need to read the body twice.

Answer (score 31):

let's do it with an example. Assume your request body has a user email like this:

```
{ email: "test@test.com" }
```

and now you want to get this email on the back-end. first, define a struct like the following:

```
    type EmailRequestBody struct {
    Email string
    }
```

Now you can easily bind the email value in your request body to the struct you defined: first, define a variable for your struct and then bind the value:

```
func ExampleFunction(c *gin.Context) {

var requestBody EmailRequestBody

   if err := c.BindJSON(&requestBody); err != nil {
       // DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR
   }

  fmt.Println(requestBody.Email)
}
```

you can easily access the email value and print it out or do whatever you need :

```
fmt.Println(requestBody.Email)
```

Answer (score 12):

Or you can use `GetRawData()` function as:

```
jsonData, err := c.GetRawData()

if err != nil{
   //Handle Error
}

err = client.Set("id", jsonData, 0).Err()
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get json body like other frameworks like express(Nodejs), you can do the following

```
bodyAsByteArray, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
jsonBody := string(bodyAsByteArray)
```

Comment: Make sure to handle the ioutil.ReadAll's error. Using underscore should be avoided because bodyAsByteArray can be nil. and the server might panic.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer by @arifur Rahman, but what if you want to access the JSON values from the request body?
Here is the solution :

```
bodyAsByteArray, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body) 
jsonBody := string(bodyAsByteArray)
```

So, the above lines will change your request body into a string. You can directly print the string, but you can not access the JSON values as this is a string. So for that, you have to unMarshal it.

Follow below code:

```
bodyAsByteArray, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
jsonMap := make(map[string]interface{})
json.Unmarshal(bodyAsByteArray, &jsonMap)
```

So if your request body is like that

> {
> "order":"1",
> "Name":"ts1" }

Then,

1. In the first case, you can't access it using jsonBody["order"]
2. In the second case, you can access it using jsonMap["order"]