# Golang Rest api data not showing in postman

Tags: go

I am facing an issue where i have made an api in Go every thing work fine but i am not getting data in postman. When i print the data in logs i am getting the data properly but it is showing blank data in postman.

authorizeModel.go

```
func GetSkillList() map[string]interface{} {
    db := GetDB()
    var (
        // id        int
        skillName string
    )
    type SkillList struct {
        name string
    }
    skillList := SkillList{}
    skillArr := []SkillList{}

    rows, err := db.Query("select DISTINCT(name) as name from skills where company_id IN ('2') and name != 'Skill Needed' order by name")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&skillName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        skillList.name = skillName
        skillArr = append(skillArr, skillList)
    }
    response := u.Message(true, "Skill list retrieved successfully")
    response["data"] = skillArr
    log.Println(skillArr)
    response["authorization"] = false
    return response
}
```

authController.go

```
var SkillTagList = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    resp := models.GetSkillList()
    u.Respond(w, resp)
}
```

routes.go

```
router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/authorize/skillTagList", controllers.SkillTagList).Methods("POST")
```

If you see authorizeModel.go i have printed my data in logs i am getting that data successfully in logs. But see the postman screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You have to export fields if you want to marshal them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have to rename `name` to `Name`

I'm not sure what is `u.Respond()`, so I will assume it's a helper function of some framework that you are using, and I will assume `u.Respond()` is internally using json.Marshal.

If your struct has unexported fields(fields name starting with lowercase letter, in your case `name`), `json.Marshal` cannot access those field, and the result won't have `name` field. That is why you are getting empty objects in JSON.