# Go Gin Bind JSON issue

Tags: go, go-gin

Strangely http POST/GET request in my code is returning empty JSON (for GET) or adding empty struct ( for POST)
Here is snip of code

```
package main
import (
   "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
type employee struct {
    id int64 `json:"id" binding:"required"`
} 
var all_employee = []employee{
    {id: 1},  
}

func getEmployees(context *gin.Context) {
    
    context.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, all_employee)
    return
}
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/allemployees", getEmployees)
}
```

Here is curl output

> curl http://localhost:9099/allemployees

> [
> {}
> ]

Comment: go.mod content "module example/web-svc  \n go 1.13 \n require github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1 "

Comment: `id` is unexported.

Answer (score 3):

That is happening because the field "id" is not exported.

To unmarshal a json to a field of a structure the field need to be exported.

Changing your model to:

```
type employee struct {
  Id int64 `json:"id" binding:"required"`
}
```

Should fix the problem.

OBS:
`id != Id`

This post have more details about it:
[JSON and dealing with unexported fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126793/json-and-dealing-with-unexported-fields)